# How to get first empty cell in a column? Google Spreadsheets API

Tags: c#, google-docs, gdata

Hi is there a fast way (csharp) to get the first empty cell in a column in a Google Spreadsheet file?
Is there any alternative to scanning the entire column?
How long (ms) would it ~ take to scan about 200 one word columns?

Comment: what did you try or how do you scan all columns/rows? can you show some code so we start from there?